# How to know which radio frequency is free to transmit data over a particular frequency to avoid interference

Tags: radio, interference

I found that some radio broadcasting stations transmit data at a particular frequency, and I was told that if I were to transmit my own at that particular frequency that I would interfere with their signal.

That got me thinking:

- How would I know when a frequency is free?
- How would I stop other signals from interfering mine?
- What kind of circuit would I use to implement this?

I am about to build a receiver and transmitter circuit, so this question popped up.

Comment: The radio spectrum is licensed and regulated. You need to check your country's regulations. You can't just broadcast on a frequency just because you find no one is using it at the moment.

Comment: @DKNguyen its a small electronics project. Is that necessary ?

Comment: Yes. You need to at least find out which bands are unlicensed and use those. And not all unlicensed bands are allocated for all uses.

Comment: Oh, i will do just that, thanks

Comment: @DKNguyen is there a way to prevent others from interfering my own signal

Comment: More power or more complicated modulation methods. Both of which are probably not possible for you at the moment. Start small, and short distances where it won't matter so much.

Comment: What frequencies are you interested in and in which country? There are a number of unlicensed bands (below certain transmitter power) in most countries but it's not the same everywhere so that's an important detail to add to your questions background information. You should also indicate the type of transmitter you intend to use.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser with more research, I would know what frequency I want to transmit at and the type of transmitter I intend to use, then I would update the question

Comment: If you don't mind saying which country you're in, folks may be able to point you to beneficial resources.

Comment: Am in Nigeria now

Answer (score 5):

- In general terms, equipment on any band needs to be licensed for use there.
- Some bands are licence-free, such as the 433MHz band in Europe, the 902MHz band in USA or the 2.4GHz band world-wide.
- In order to use a license-free band, the equipment still needs to conform to various regulations. In Europe this is the Radio Equipment Directive + harmonized standards, in USA it is the FCC Part 15 Directive.
- The general policy when two conforming devices make access to a license-free band is first come, first serve. Specific bands will have specific requirements such as narrowband channels, "low duty cycle" transmitters (only send 10% of the time etc) or pseudo-random frequency hopping (as seen in FCC Part 15).
- Some bands and technologies implement "clear channel assessment" which either means that they simply read RSSI and sit and wait until the channel is free, or implement some smarter algorithm for keeping track of the band and finding a free channel.

Peeking at your profile, I'm guessing this is for Nigeria? I can't find anything about license-free bands in the frequency allocation table from [www.ncc.gov.ng](http://www.ncc.gov.ng), other than 2.4GHz. They use exactly the same technical EN/ETSI standards as EU though.

Comment: That's a great answer! I'd also add that if you have a radio license, usually people agree to frequency channels to use for data and use something liked CSMA to check before transmitting and to share the channel with each other.